# How to convert other time to UTC time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my table the time is stored in epoch seconds like "1619067630", this time is PST time.
When i am trying to convert using TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(1619067630) i am getting "2021-04-22 05:00:30 UTC" (this is correct PST time). I want to convert this PST time to "**UTC**" time and it should take care of day light savings as well.

please help me on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what PST time could mean, other than the epoch is relative to time in PST.  If so, you could use:

```
select timestamp_add(timestamp('1970-01-01', 'America/Los_Angeles'), interval 1619067630 second)
```

Comment: This can add seconds to the timestamp, what about the day light saving

Comment: @kalyan4uonly . . . Your question doesn't mention daylight saving time.  It only mentions PST.